# Automatically add spaces VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to automatically add spaces in VS Code for example:
    `for(int i=0;i<10;i++)`
turns into:
    `for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )`
This feature is available in visual studio and I'm used to it, so I was wondering if there was some way to do it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow these steps :

1. right click your document and select **FORMAT DOCUMENT WITH**
2. select **CONFIGURE DEFAULT FORMATTER...**
3. select **C/C++**
4. Now go to settings and search for **format on type** and enable it

~DONE

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible yet, unless you create your own [Formatter Extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/11/15/formatters-best-practices)

Answer (score 0):

Just go to settings and search "format".
There's some options for you!
Choose your formatter and if you like enable other options!
I turned them On!